# Content Security Policy - external affiliate links + Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, html, security, content-security-policy

I'm currently working on a website/blog project, using HTML, CSS and JavaScript only.
I'm also using Google Adsense (inline ads + letting google place ads automatically) and affiliate links (from 1 source only).

When running a Lighthouse Report I get 100% in Best Practices, however, the message "**Ensure CSP is effective against XSS attacks**" got me scratching my head.

I've tried a few combinations to get the Content Security Policy (CSP) to work with Google Adsense but so far I've only been able to either completely block ads display or get error messages.

Code I used:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com; object-src 'self';">
```

I wonder if such Content Security Policy (CSP)is strictly necessary in my case.
So here is what I'm hoping to answer:

*1- How can I implement the Content Security Policy (CSP) so it works with Google Adsense and how can I add the CSP for the affiliate program I use (assuming CSP is applicable in my case)?*

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly [AdSense is not designed to be used with CSP](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/102839782?hl=en&msgid=103611259). They way AdSense might be adding content (potentially scripts) to your page may not be possible without making sure that all content is compatible and users are passing a correct nonce. AdSense have probably concluded that the high adoption cost, correlating to low usage, makes it not worth the investment for any party.